# Mysql Vs NoSql For fast searching

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I know that this question seems vague but as I am not very much clear with the concept of NoSql(mongo or casandra) so thought of putting my question here to get it clarified and any input will be more helpful for deciding and designing my application more elegantly as application is more used for searching item .

I need to design a database where insertion and update will not be major bottlenecks, but I have data with millions of records. Users should be able to access them as quickly as possible .

If I use Mysql then I need to use index to get the data faster and use cache mechanism in application.

I was wondering if fast search could be achieved via NoSql (Mongo or casandra) rather than Mysql?

Comment: Access by what? Please be _a lot_ more specific om what you want to achieve.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg  actually I have million of data  and user can search it i want searching faster so if i go to mysql i need to index the data but if I use nosql database like mongo would searching of data can be faster than mysql ?

Comment: An article from MongoDB's website - [NoSQL vs Relational Databases](https://www.mongodb.com/scale/nosql-vs-relational-databases). Evaluating your data structure, relationship and content type against the comment _Relational databases were built in an era where data was fairly structured and clearly defined by their relationships. NoSQL databases are designed to handle unstructured data (e.g., texts, social media posts, video, email) which makes up much of the data that exists today_ could indicate some of the things that may need to be considered while making a choice.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using relational database for insert and update and search engine (elasticsearch) for publishing. That way you can get insanely good results.

Comment: ohh. Thanks for downvote. Why bother commenting whats wrong with my answer.